# Picking a random line from a text file

Tags: c++

I need to write an 8 ball code that has eleven options to display and it needs to pull from a text file. I have it taking lines from the text file but sometimes it takes an empty line with no writing. And I need it to only take a line that has writing.
Here are that options it needs to draw from:
Yes, of course!
Without a doubt, yes.
You can count on it.
For sure!Ask me later.
I'm not sure.
I can't tell you right now.
I'll tell you after my nap.
No way!I don't think so.
Without a doubt, no.
The answer is clearly NO.

```
string line;
int random = 0;
int numOfLines = 0;
ifstream File("file.txt");

srand(time(0));
random = rand() % 50;

while (getline(File, line))
{
    ++numOfLines;

    if (numOfLines == random)
    {
        cout << line;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: If your file has 11 lines, what do you expect to read when `random` is equal to e.g. `40`?

Comment: So you're saying that if the line is empty; you want it to ignore it and look at the next line?  Have you looked at the keyword `continue`?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you need to either make the text lines all the same length, or use a database (table) of file positions.

### Using File Positions

Minimally, create a `std::vector<pos_type>`.
Next read the lines from the file, recording the file position of the beginning of the string:

```
std::vector<std::pos_type> text_line_positions;
std::string text;
std::pos_type file_position = 0;
while (std::getline(text_file, text)
{
    text_line_positions.push_back(file_position);

    // Read the start position of the next line.
    file_position = text_file.tellg();
}
```

To read a line from a file, get the file position from the database, then seek to it.

```
std::string text_line;
std::pos_type file_position = text_line_positions[5];
text_file.seekg(file_position);
std::getline(text_file, text_line);
```

The expression, `text_line_positions.size()` will return the number of text lines in the file.

### If File Fits In Memory

If the file fits in memory, you could use `std::vector<string>`:

```
std::string text_line;
std::vector<string> database;
while (getline(text_file, text_line))
{
    database.push_back(text_line);
}
```

To print the 10 line from the file:

```
std::cout << "Line 10 from file: " << database[9] << std::endl;
```

The above techniques minimize the amount of reading from the file.